# Marking angles in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide, decorations

I am trying to reproduce an example from (an excellent) manual on `tkz-euclide`. Here is an MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
            \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,5/0/A,3/4/B}
            \tkzMarkAngle[size = 4,mark = x,
            arc=ll,mkcolor = red,mkpos=.33](A,O,B)
            \tkzMarkAngle[size = 2,mark = ||,
            arc=ll,mkcolor = blue,mkpos=.66](A,O,B)
            \tkzDrawLines(O,A O,B)
            \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

But, no… Here is the output:

[image]

Obviously, something is wrong with the size of the marking. However, when I increase the size parameter, say:
`\tkzMarkAngle[size = 15,mark = x,arc=ll,mkcolor = red,mkpos=.33](A,O,B)`
then it becomes even worse (note how far away to the right the cross marking is):
[image]

Even worse than that: when I remove the cross markings from the arcs (I like to distinguish the angles with the number of arcs since I have a few in my drawing), they don't disappear:

```
    \tkzMarkAngle[size = 15,arc=ll](A,O,B)  
    \tkzMarkAngle[size = 2, arc=ll](A,O,B)
```

Result:
[image]

Hash-mark is still there — very far to the right…

**Update**: When I reinstall TexLive (basically LaTeX itself), it updated all the packages tkz-euklid including. Everything is working now without the units. Thanks Alain!

Comment: Give me the version you use because since version 4 you don't need a unit anymore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future generations: The trick is that you have to **put the units** for the size of the arc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,5/0/A,3/4/B}
        \tkzMarkAngle[size = 4cm,mark = x,
        arc=ll,mkcolor = red,mkpos=.33](A,O,B)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size = 2cm,mark = ||,
        arc=ll,mkcolor = blue,mkpos=.66](A,O,B)
        \tkzDrawLines(O,A O,B)
        \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your version of ` tkz-euclide` ?  and you have a problem with the colors !

Comment: I wish I knew how to check it. I use TeXStudio 4.2.2 to compile Latex files. It load the packages automatically. How to check the version of tkz-euklid? Although, I hope I have the latest since I don't need to load tikz or \usetikzlibrary{all}

Comment: I don't have problems with colors, I just use monochromatic theme on my computer to minimize distractions. The colors are fine if I switch the black-and-white setting off.

Comment: In the file .log you can find the version of `tkz-euclide`

Comment: I guess I have 3.06 version: 

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide.sty
2020/03/18 3.06c tkz-euclide.sty
Package: tkz-euclide 2020/03/18 3.06c for euclidan geometry

Comment: Ok now I understand. With 3.06 you need to give the units. With versions higher than 4, the package has become independent from `tkz-base` and it becomes a package only dedicated to Euclidean geometry. The only possible unit is `cm`. You don't have to put the units. I did this to isolate the definition macros and to introduce in a short time the calculations with `lua`. Note that for plots and options in `TikZ` like `line width=1pt` or `above right=12pt` the units are still used because they depend on `TikZ`. If you have a problem you can send me an email (email in the doc.)

Comment: Thank you, Alain! I reinstall TeXLive and now everything is fine. The compiler gave the error on the 'cm' units. I deleted the units and everything went smoothly. Thanks again for tkz-euclid. It is really the best! I used it for every single picture in the second volume (on 2 dimentional geometry) of my book.

Answer (score 1):

With version 4.05. Since version 4, it is no longer necessary to add the units (which can cause errors) because the unit is "only cm". Note that at the same time `tkz-euclide` has become independent of `tkz-base`. If you use both packages then you have to load `tkz-base` first. The next version is 4.1 with dot product, power circle, radical axis etc. in several days and the next version 5 will use `lua` for calculations.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 
  
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
          \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,5/0/A,3/4/B}
          \tkzMarkAngle[size = 4,mark = x,
          arc=ll,mkcolor = red,mkpos=.33](A,O,B)
          \tkzMarkAngle[size = 2,mark = ||,
          arc=ll,mkcolor = blue,mkpos=.66](A,O,B)
          \tkzDrawLines(O,A O,B)
          \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B)
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've asked a related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/710071/tkz-euclide-set-style-of-angle-marks-globally