# tkz-euclide: Set style of angle marks globally

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

How can I control globally the styles of angles and marks, particularly the color and line thickness/length, with `tkz-euclide`? I am not sure how to set styles like `mkcolor` globally.

I'm looking to reproduce the figure below with tkz-euclide in such a way that I can control the styles globally with `\tkzSetUpStyle`. I'd like to be able to leverage `mark=||` and other mark styles, but I need control over colors and length (with the defaults here, the `||` marks are in black and too long). For instance, in `\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5,mark=x,arc=ll,mkcolor=orange,new](A,C,O)` I'd like to have `mkcolor=orange` set globally inside the `new` style.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}% needed for experiments

\tkzSetUpStyle[color=orange,angle radius=15pt]{new}

\tikzset{%
  smaller arc/.style={angle radius=10pt}, 
  double arc/.style={double,double distance=2pt},
  triple arc/.style={double distance=4pt, 
      pic actions/.append code=\tikzset{postaction={draw}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/0/B,1/4/C}
  \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){$A$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
  \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}

  % compute the center
  \tkzInCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}\tkzDrawPoint[new](O)

% tikz/pic way, because mark colors and styles are complicated with tkz-euclide
  \path (A) -- (B) -- (C)
    pic[new, double arc, draw]{angle=C--B--O}
    pic[new, double arc, draw, smaller arc]{angle=O--B--A}
    pic[new, draw]{angle=O--A--C}
    pic[new, draw, smaller arc]{angle=B--A--O}
    pic[new, triple arc, draw]{angle=A--C--O} 
    pic[new, triple arc, draw, smaller arc]{angle=O--C--B} 
    -- cycle;

  \draw [new] (A) -- (O)--(intersection of  A--O and B--C);
  \draw [new] (B) -- (O)--(intersection of  B--O and A--C);
  \draw [new] (C) -- (O)--(intersection of  C--O and B--A);

  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)% draw this last
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

P.S. Any general advice on coding and/or suggestions for prettification of the figure are welcome, of course. [image]

Comment: Something like `arc style` will be added in the next version. Indeed, it's not easy to find `tkzmkangle` in the code.

Comment: I looked into the possibility of modifying the macro, but it would require me to revise a lot of code. The macro that marks angles uses the one that draws arcs. I haven't found any easy way to have a global style. I can introduce a style but it will only apply to the styles defined by TikZ (color, style, line width) but not arc, size, for example. I'll give it another try in a while.

Comment: Very kind of you to look into it! I wouldn't worry too much. I think setting `/tkzmkangle/mkcolor=orange` in a style declaration in the preamble essentially solves the issue for anyone (like myself) who likes to set styles globally for multiple documents and never look at them again! It's not a piece of code I'll be able to memorize, but there is now a good place to find it: here! Thanks Alain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options are a bit hidden, but you can access them by prefixing with `/tkzmkangle/`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\tkzSetUpStyle[
    color=orange,
    /tkzmkangle/mkcolor=orange,
    /tkzmkangle/mark=||,
]{new}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,5/0/B,1/4/C}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](C){$C$}
    
    % compute the center
    \tkzInCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}
    \tkzDrawPoint[new](O)
    
    \tkzInterLL(A,O)(B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
    \tkzInterLL(B,O)(A,C)\tkzGetPoint{b}
    \tkzInterLL(C,O)(A,B)\tkzGetPoint{c}
    \tkzDrawSegments[new](A,a B,b C,c)
    
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.6, arc=lll, new](A,C,O)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5, arc=lll, new](O,C,B)

    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C) % draw this last
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well done for extracting `tkzmkangle` from the code!

Comment: Great answer, thanks Jasper! @AlainMatthes, I'll pick Jasper's answer as it answers my question directly, but I feel I will be spending the next few weeks investigating all the novelties you offer in your answer. Thanks to both of you for great tips!

Comment: @PatrickT Actually, I looked into the code on CTAN and found this style. So, you could of course also do that if you want ti know more about this. But to make sense of it, you also need to know how keys in PGF work.

Comment: Thanks Jasper! I don't mind a few magical lines in the preamble! :-)

Answer (score 3):

First observation: the macro `tkzMarkAngle` doesn't have its own style like points or lines. I can add a style like `angle style` in a future version. That said, it won't fundamentally improve everything, as there are plenty of options.

As Jasper Habicht pointed out, you need to specify the path to use the size and arc styles. These are specific to tkz-euclide. With `\tkzSetUpStyle` you can only use TikZ styles.

I've given a solution with tkz-elements, but the second part concerns tkz-euclide, which is common.

Comments on the code `tkz-elements`.
You can replace it with the part of your code that creates the points. ENext, compile with lualatex. We define the fixed points A,B and C. z.A,z.B and z.C are linked to the affixes of the points. Then we define the triangle `T.ABC` which, when created, has attributes such as `incenter`, but we can use a,b and c for the lengths of the sides, or alpha, beta and gamma for the angles, and so on.
For bisector, the first bisector is that of vertex A, (1) and (2) then indicate that we're moving on to the next vertex ...
The final subtlety is `.pb`. The bisector is an object of class `line` whose first attributes are two points referenced by pa and pb. Here, `pb` represents the foot of the bisector.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tkzelements}
   z.A    = point : new (0 , 0)
   z.B    = point : new (5 , 0)
   z.C    = point : new (1 , 4)
   T.ABC  = triangle : new ( z.A , z.B , z.C )
   z.O    = T.ABC.incenter
   z.E    = T.ABC : bisector ().pb
   z.F    = T.ABC : bisector (1).pb
   z.G    = T.ABC : bisector (2).pb
\end{tkzelements}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ new/.style ={ color=orange },
                     one/.style ={ new,/tkzmkangle/size=.5 },
                     two/.style ={ new,/tkzmkangle/size=.6 },
                     l/.style   ={ /tkzmkangle/arc=l },
                     ll/.style  ={ /tkzmkangle/arc=ll },
                     lll/.style ={ /tkzmkangle/arc=lll }
                    ]
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegments[new](A,E B,F C,G)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,E,F,G,O)

\begin{scope}[one]
  \tkzMarkAngles[l](B,A,E)
  \tkzMarkAngles[ll](C,B,F)
  \tkzMarkAngles[lll](A,C,G)
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[two]
  \tkzMarkAngles[l](E,A,C)
  \tkzMarkAngles[ll](F,B,A)
  \tkzMarkAngles[lll](G,C,B)
\end{scope}

\tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. This is a great figure. Thanks for suggesting all these new tricks. Could you comment briefly below why you compile with lualatex and should I consider switching to it? Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT `lualatex` because `tkz-elements` is based on Lua. All calculations are performed in Lua. It's much easier to program mathematical functions than with `TeX`. I look for all the points of construction of the figure then I draw with tkz-euclide or TikZ. It's more complete with tkz-elements because I have many powerful tools (complexes, barycenter, matrices, equation solving) and above all it's faster for calculations and very, very precise!

Comment: Great, I'm going to adopt `lualatex` then! Wonderful package `tkz-euclide` is! I'll start exploring `tkz-elements` right away!

Comment: @Alain Matthes I can not get the result.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 What is your version of tkz-elements? have you compiled with lualatex? what version of lualatex? and what error do you have? you can send me your files to the e-mail address indicated on the readme or in the documentation.

Comment: FYI all: I compiled the code with `LuaLaTeX` in the `TeXstudio` IDE and the 2023 `TeXlive` distribution, and it worked without errors. The only very minor thing is that the border/margins set in a `standalone` class were not respected. Perhaps the bounding box has to be reset before compiling? It didn't bother me so I didn't investigate further. Great code!